# Error Run Android First Program

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, haxm

[image]

I have Windows 7.

I installed Android Studio Bundle it works but the problem is that when I Create run the first program, it shows this error:

**emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!**

Even I check Android SDK Manager:- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer) - installed

And I run the installer program, intelhaxm.exe and still got error now what to do.

[image]

Comment: from the bios settings of your PC enable virtualization of your PC. then restart PC to install this HAXM

Comment: how to find bios setting and where in system could you please let me know the process of this? thanks in advance.

Comment: You enter BIOS setup when your PC first boots. Look for messages telling you what key to hit.

Comment: Right answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34282302/4919237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you download HAXM through the SDK manager, it only downloads the installer program. You still have to open up the folder and run the install program. As described [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows):

> *"The SDK Manager will download the installer to the "extras" directory, under the main SDK directory. Even though the SDK manager
>   says "Installed" it actually means that the Intel HAXM executable was
>   downloaded. You will still need to run the installer from the "extras"
>   directory to get it installed."*

Now you have to use Windows File Explorer to open the extras folder and run the installer program, `intelhaxm.exe`. On my machine, this installer program is located in `C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\`. Please note that if you're going to drill down into this path, you may need to enable viewing of hidden items in File Explorer, since the `AppData` folder is usually hidden.

Comment: thanks for reply and I attached the image also and its showing already installed now what i will do

Comment: Right. In this case, all "Installed" means is that the installer program has been downloaded.  You still have to run it.  See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for reply i run the installer program but got error, now what I will do.

Comment: See above - you need to change your BIOS settings.